# passing object through intent from background service to an activity

Tags: android, service, android-activity

I want to pass a custom made vector object containing data from background service to an activity in order to updating UI of that activity.
I am not able to pass my data via intent. Please assist me what i need to do..

Following is the code snippet that i am using. In below code I want to pass article list to an activity.

```
Vector<RowData> getArticleLog() throws JSONException{

    Vector<RowData> articleList = new Vector<RowData>();

    RowData rd;
    InputStream is = null;
    String result = null;
    JSONArray jarray = new JSONArray();

    //Add data to be send.
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("article_title", "Flying Horse"));

    try {

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        // for local server xampp
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/groupbook/return_article_log.php");

        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();
        Log.i("postData", response.getStatusLine().toString());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "json error : " + e.toString());
    }
    //convert response to string
    try {
         BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
         StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
         String line = null;
         while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                 sb.append(line + "\n");
         }
         is.close();

         result=sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
         Log.e(TAG, "Error converting result "+e.toString());
    }

    try {
        jarray = new JSONArray(result);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //return jArray in the form of Array list;
    JSONObject rowElement = null;
    int viewers = 0;
    int votes = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
        rowElement = jarray.getJSONObject(i);

        viewers = rowElement.getInt("viewers");
        votes = rowElement.getInt("votes");

        rd = new RowData(i, 
                rowElement.getString("article_title"), 
                Integer.toString(i), 
                rowElement.getString("last_post_by"),
                "2 hours", 
                rowElement.getString("catagory_tag"), 
                Integer.toString(viewers), 
                rowElement.getString("privacy_tag"), 
                Integer.toString(votes), 
                rowElement.getString("catagory_title"));
        articleList.add(rd);
    }

    return articleList;
}
```

RowData class is as follows :

```
public class RowData {

protected int mId;
public String articleTitle;
public String articleCounter;
public String lastPostBy;
public String updatedTime;
public String catagoryTag;
public String viewingNow;
public String privacyTag;
public String votes;
public String catagoryTitle;

public RowData(int mId, String articleTitle, String articleCounter,
        String lastPostBy, String updatedTime, String catagoryTag,
        String viewingNow, String privacyTag, String votes,
        String catagoryTitle) {
    this.mId = mId;
    this.articleTitle = articleTitle;
    this.articleCounter = articleCounter;
    this.lastPostBy = lastPostBy;
    this.updatedTime = updatedTime;
    this.catagoryTag = catagoryTag;
    this.viewingNow = viewingNow;
    this.privacyTag = privacyTag;
    this.votes = votes;
    this.catagoryTitle = catagoryTitle;
}
}
```

Is following way is right way??

```
private void DisplayingInfo() throws JSONException{
    Log.d(TAG, "entered DisplayLoggingInfo");
    intent.putExtra("articleLog", getArticleLog());
    sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you can do is to make your custom class implement `Serializable` (or `Parcelable`), send the serializable object with `putExtra()` method to the activity and use `getSerializableExtra()` on your activity to get it.

---

**Edit 1:** 
a quick example:

In your custom class:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class YourCustomVectorClass implements Serializable {
    // ...
}
```

In your service where you want to start the activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(yourContext, yourActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("theNameOfTheObject", yourObject);
startActivity(intent);
```

In your activity:

```
YourCustomVectorClass yourVector = (YourCustomVectorClass) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("theNameOfTheObject");
```

---

**Edit 2:** After reading the question again, I realized that you're passing a `Vector` of `RowData` objects to your Activity.

Since [`Java Vector class`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html) implements `Serializable`, I think you shouldn't do anything but passing the vector to the activity using `putExtra()` and get it with `getSerializableExtra()` on the Activity.

Comment: Thank you so much for such nice and quick reply. Please elaborate one thing more that should i make RowData class Serializable or class containing getArticleLog method?? Above getArticleLog method has been written in background service..

Comment: I have checked with and without Serializable but when i use getSerializableExtra its getting exception. I have a question that getSerializableExtra return Serializable or String??

Comment: it returns **`Object`**. You should cast it to it's actual type (which is **`Vector<RowData>`** in your case). So your code will look like `Vector<RowData> receivedObject = (Vector<RowData>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("theNameOfTheObject");`